# Replacing '\' in NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I am trying to replace \' which is being added to the string that comes from server.

I tried following but its not working:

```
 if([ str rangeOfString: @"\""].location != NSNotFound){

            str = [ str  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\"" withString:@""];


        }
```

Please help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"\" is an escape character in strings, so that the string `"\""` just contains a double-quote character. To represent a backslash, you need to escape it: `"\\"` is a string containing a backslash.

Comment: My string is What\'s up.. I will try with "\\"